# AngularJS: Better way to display success messages

Tags: angularjs

```
$('body').on('click', '#save-btn', function () { 
      $('#greetingsModal').modal('show'); 
 });


<div id="greetingsModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="alert alert-success">        
     <a href="../admin/Supplier" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
    <strong>Well done!</strong>.
</div>
```

I want to display a popup message using the above styles whenever 'save-btn' is clicked. The above code works fine but there is a lot of time delay by doing it this way. Is there any way to display such a alert message **using angular**?

Comment: You need to find out what's is causing the delay. In general we don't use angular to display something faster, it's just a organised way to doing things than bare JQuery.

Answer (score 14):

Bootrstrap-UI has pretty good alert. We can use the same place for all alerts. Just modify content.

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="showSuccessAlert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool('showSuccessAlert')" >×</button>
   <strong>Done!</strong> {{successTextAlert}}
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.successTextAlert = "Some content";
$scope.showSuccessAlert = true;
....
// switch flag
$scope.switchBool = function(value) {
   $scope[value] = !$scope[value];
};
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/718/)</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

if you interesting to put alert into dialog, here is other Demo in <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/heDUTa?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank You. This does the work but I don't want to show it on the same page instead I want to pop out saying 'Done!'. I mean which should be similar to `alert("done!");` using the same styles as above. How can I do that?

Comment: This would be cool created as a directive so we could just pass in a success message or error message in the controller when a function (such as save button) is clicked. Then in your default layout you could place this message near the top of the page and it can be used throughout.

Answer (score 2):

I would be wary of mixing jQuery and Angular, it works but can get messy.  You may be interested in the Bootstrap-UI Modal here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal
It can do what you want and more.